# Run function on each element on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to check if ANY of the parents of a certain element are a  tag? At the moment, it just checks the immediate parent, but I was wondering if there's a way to check if it contains within any ankor tag at all?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="website">Load Content</a>
        <a href=""><img width="200" height="200" class="zoom" /></a>
        <a href=""><div><img width="78" height="101" class="zoom" /></div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.zoomBox {
    position:absolute;  
    opacity:0;
    background: url('http://www.shannonhochkins.com/_images/505706e8965f59080b0016a1') no-repeat center center;    
}
```

JavaScript:

```
zoom = function() {    
zoomBoxClass = 'zoomBox';
zoomContainer = $('.zoom');
zoomContainer.each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().is("a")) {
        var $el = $('<div class="' + zoomBoxClass + '"></div>').insertBefore($(this)),
            zwid = $(this).width(),
            zhei = $(this).height(),
            zpx = $(this).position().left,
            zpy = $(this).position().top;
        $el.css({
            width: zwid,
            height: zhei,
            top: zpy,
            left: zpx
        });;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    zoom();
    $("." + zoomBoxClass).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 'slow');
    });
    $("." + zoomBoxClass).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

It does work, but not properly when it hits the second one.

I need to be able to run the function for every class that exists on the page individually. Is this possible?

Comment: What does "every class that has the class "zoom"." mean? Every class that has the string `zoom` within its `className`? Or does it mean `every element that has the class "zoom"`?

Comment: sorry, every element that has the class zoom, not to worry the answer has been posted below! Thankyou for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `.each()`

```
zoomContainer.each(function() {
    var zoomBox = $('<div class="zoomBox"></div>').insertBefore($(this));
    // anything else you want to do to zoomBox
});
```

zoomContainer is a collection of jQuery objects, the `.each()` will iterate through each one, the context (this) refers to the individual zoomContainer jQuery object in the loop.

In context of your code example:

```
zoom = function() {
    zoomBoxClass = 'zoomBox';
    zoomContainer = $('.zoom');

    zoomContainer.each(function () {
        var $el = $('<div class="' + zoomBoxClass + '"></div>').insertBefore($(this)),
            zwid = $(this).width(),
            zhei = $(this).height(),
            zpx = $(this).position().left,
            zpy = $(this).position().top;

        $el.css({
            width: zwid,
            height: zhei,
            top: zpy,
            left: zpx
        });
    });
};
```

If you want to traverse up the DOM tree until you reach a specific tag if it exists you can use jquery's `.closest(selector)`

```
`$(this).closest('a');`
```

If you want to check if `.closest()` returned anything you can check its length property is > 0

```
var $a = $(this).closest('a');

if ($a.length > 0) {
    // do stuff with $a here
}
```

Comment: That certainly did the trick! Thankyou heaps @Mark! Saved me a world of time!

Comment: I have edited my original question if you wouldn't mind having a quick look @Mark?

Comment: Updated my answer with .closest()